# Delete a file and its parents directories if they're empty. ( Java )

Tags: java, java-7, java-io

I'm trying to do a simple method that deletes a file its upper directories if they are empty till it reaches a base directory, but I cannot make it work.

It deletes the file, its parent directory, but, its next parent isn't deleted as it throws a `DirectoryNotEmptyException`. It really is empty as there was only one child directory and it was deleted in the previous iteration.

So, the file is deleted, its parent is deleted, and it stops there, no more upper directories are deleted.

EDITED: (modified code)

It seems that there is a delay deleting directories, so in the next check of the emptiness state of the directory, the previous one isn't yet deleted. So I've added a while loop to check until the directory doesn't exist. I don't know if this is it or not a bad technique but it works for my needs.

```
public static void removeFileAndParentsIfEmpty(Path path) throws IOException {
    if(path == null || path.endsWith(FilesPath.BILLS_DIRECTORY)) {
        return;
    }
    if (Files.isRegularFile(path)){
        Files.deleteIfExists(path);
    } else if (Files.isDirectory(path)){
        if(path.toFile().list().length == 0){
            Files.delete(path);
            while(Files.exists(path));
        }else{
            return;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
    removeFileAndParentsIfEmpty(path.getParent());
}
```

If anyone can give a better solution, the question is still open for approval.
Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the method stop when the exception is thrown, I mean, if Files.delete() throws a DirectoryNotEmptyException, it is catched and method ends without doing another recursive call, or I am wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed the re-call, my bad :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a base condition for an empty directory, so on the second go-through your recursive function it attempts to delete the empty directories parent, before the directory itself. A simple code change should be sufficient to fix this:

```
public static void removeFileAndParentsIfEmpty(Path path)
        throws IOException {
    if(path == null || path.endsWith(BASEPATH)) return;

    if (Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
        Files.deleteIfExists(path);
    } else if(Files.isDirectory(path)) {
        try {
            Files.delete(path);
        } catch(DirectoryNotEmptyException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    removeFileAndParentsIfEmpty(path.getParent());
}
```

Comment: It should work like that but it doesnt. It seems like Files.delete() doesn't delete the directory instantly, and when it's called again in the next recursive call, the previous directory still isn't deleted, is that possible?

Comment: I had to do a little trick that works, but I don't think it would be a good use.
After deleting the directory, just call: ´while(Files.exists(path));´ that will wait until the directory doesn't exists and continue the recursive walk.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest your problem lies here

```
Files.delete(path.getParent());
removeFileAndParentsIfEmpty(path.getParent());
```

You delete the parent folder, the call your method again to try and delete the same folder...seen as it no longer exists, the second call simply falls through and exists without doing anything.

I'd also add a check in to see if the directory is empty, but you are right, the exception will catch it, I just see it as a bad practice to use and exception for condition you're looking for - IMHO

Comment: I'll look into that. If you say it's not a good practice I trust you, thanks for the advice. I just wanted to save code.

Comment: IMHO exceptions are "unexpected" conditions, you are anticipating this condition, there fore it's not "unexpected". Java can tend to throw a lot of exceptions some times, but having worked a C based system for the last few years, I prefer the exceptions over error levels and error lookups :P

Comment: can you check the modification I've made to the code and tell me if it's ok?, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the while loop is for, but otherwise it looks okay

Comment: The while loop is to wait until the directory is deleted, because in the next recursive call the previous directory isn't yet deleted.

Comment: Then you probably should have a break condition in case the directory can't be deleted (it at be okay, but it raises alarm bells to me)

Comment: It isn't like it can't be deleted, in wich case it will throw an exception, but seems like a delay in the directory deletion. I know the while loop doesn't look good, but is the only way I've managed to make it work. Thanks for your time!

Comment: As I said, it's probably okay, it just raises alarm bells to me ;)

Comment: Well, the delay is due to the folder being opened in the explorer.